# UIView's color cannot be changed programmatically after setting named color

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, interface-builder

Even when you create a fresh single view project (Xcode 9.2), create a single named color in an asset catalog, set the background color of the main view controller to this color in IB, and try to update the background color in viewDidLoad, the background color won't change. Have other people experienced this? Is this normal behavior?

```
view.backgroundColor = .red // Doesn't work, the asset color set in IB remains
```

Comment: Not normal. Please post your code if you want help.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is marked as off-topic. I've given the shortest path to reproducing the issue. Obviously, the desired behavior is that the color does change. I updated my question with the code...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Super interesting and you are correct it does not change the color value as expected.  There must be some delay as to when IB attributes are set in the super class.  Wrapping the color change in DispatchQueue.main.async makes it work in viewDidLoad.  Probably because this code would be processed last after whatever the super class is doing with IB attributes.  Hope this solves the issue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```

Also in viewDidLayoutSubviews and viewDidAppear it works without the DispatchQueue but has the same behavior as viewDidLoad in viewWillAppear of not working as expected.

Comment: Cool, thanks. You would expect at viewDidLoad the view to be ready to touch. I will file a radar with Apple.

Comment: @JorisWeimar Completely agree. Make me wonder if these attributes are loaded asynchronously. Paste the number here and I will dupe it.

Comment: BTW, while observering didSet on backgroundColor it turns out the color is set three times. Once initially, then once by me in viewDidLoad and then subsequently again (it looks like in a different color space).

Comment: Any other solutions rather than dispatching?

Comment: @CsabiVidó viewDidAppear or viewDidLayoutSubviews no dispatch needed.

Comment: I will try to find another solution and post it here as dispatching in viewDidLoad can cause some undesirable display delays

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in iOS 13 (tested building on iOS 13 with Xcode 11 beta 4)

Comment: Any idea if this was fixed in Xcode or in iOS13 or a combination of the two? Cheers, Z.